# Expo SDK40 upgrade TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '..._core.Platform.select...')

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a problem, once upgrading to SDK 40 from SDK39 when I try to start the app the build fails with the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEGrM.jpg)

I tried expo start -c, remove and reinstall the node_modules. Any other ideas?

```
  Expo CLI 4.1.3 environment info:
System:
  OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
  Shell: 4.3.48 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 12.18.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/bin/node
  npm: 6.14.11 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/bin/npm
SDKs:
  Android SDK:
    API Levels: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
    Build Tools: 27.0.0, 27.0.1, 27.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.0, 28.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.2
    System Images: android-23 | Intel x86 Atom, android-23 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-23 | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-24 | ARM 64 v8a, android-24 | ARM EABI v7a, android-24 | Intel x86 Atom, android-24 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-24 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-24 | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a, android-24 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-24 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-24 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-25 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-25 | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a, android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-26 | Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
    Android NDK: 20.0.5594570
npmPackages:
  expo: ^40.0.0 => 40.0.1 
  react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
  react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz => 0.63.2 
  react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18 
npmGlobalPackages:
  expo-cli: 4.1.3
Expo Workflow: managed
```

thank you all for any help with this!

Comment: hi there! this is not sufficient information to help with the issue. you should check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or this debugging guide https://gist.github.com/brentvatne/5ac00cba0c70b7a06b89a56787d6bc4a to get to the source of what is causing the issue for you

Comment: hey, any luck? i have the same issue

Comment: @obiwankenoobi 
In my project the problem was caused by an old version of the highcharts library.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this version

yarn add expo-linking@1.0.7
```